# Need to clear Duplicates in a combobox in c++

Tags: c++

Basically Title. I have a class with multiple duplicates and I need to get rid of them in my combobox but I have no idea how. Here is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxInventaire; i++) {
        if (item[i] != NULL) {
            cmb_item->Items->Add(gcnew String(item[i]->getNom().c_str()));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxEmployes; i++) {
        if (employe[i] != NULL) {
            cmb_employe->Items->Add(gcnew String(employe[i]->getNom().c_str()));
        }
    }
```

I have more than 20 duplicates the first one. It's a list of items I am using (ex: desktop, laptop, etc) i have stored every one of them in a class with a different id, but their name remains the same, as in desktop.

There must be a way to remove duplicates in those. I have searched everywhere with no luck, I guess you guys here could help me with that.

Thank you!

Comment: Native C++ has no such thing as a combo box, String, or gcnew. Please tag your question with the correct languages or technologies.

Comment: I am using windows forms

Comment: It looks to me that you are using much more than Windows Forms. Perhaps, Microsoft C++ Extensions and the CLR. It is important for you to know the difference between managed C++ and native C++. They are completely different languages.

Comment: While the OP is clearly using managed C++, this question would probably apply equally well in Qt or iOS.  The solution I show uses no additional syntax than the original post; I am not sure that additional tags would be helpful to others looking for an answer to a similar problem (and that is what tags are for).

Comment: Of course, saying that the OP should know the difference between managed C++ and standard C++ is true.  However they are not completely different languages.  I believe it is true to say that managed C++ is a pure extension to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to copy the names into a std::set, and then copy them out of the set into the combo box.

```
std::set<std::string> names;
for (int i = 0; i < maxInventaire; i++) {
    if (item[i] != NULL) {
        names.insert(item[i]->getNom())
    }
}
for (const auto& name: names) {
    cmb_item->Items->Add(gcnew String(name.c_str()));
}
```

You can also use `std::unordered_set`, but really the performance difference only becomes significant when you have vastly too many entries for a combo-box, and having the entries in alphabetical order is probably easier than some random order (which is what `unordered_set` will give).

Comment: Totally fixed it. Thank you so much!